# Is this python list relevant for merge sort?

Tags: python, list, shell, dictionary, mergesort

Does anyone know how to merge sort this list?

```
listd = [[1,3,"5"],4,5,69,{"b":"so","c":"d",6:8},2,4,"help",2,334]
```

I expect this list will be sorted from smallest to largest. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: in order to sort the elements of a list you must be able to determine if an element is smaller, equal or larger than another. It's not clear in your list how the different datatypes compare to each other. You need to first define what "smallest" and "largest" mean

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) feel free to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please make sure to 'mark' the answer if it solved your problem see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort a list, it should possible to compare the elements in the list and figure out which is larger and which is smaller. There is no default definition to compare different types of data types when using python sort. Since your list has different data types if you try to sort this using the `list.sort()` function it will raise an error.